# Floating error with form HTML & CSS Media queries when changing to accommodate to certain screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a new website and during the cross-platform media CSS (for changing the website's layout to accommodate to certain screen sizes), it became evident to me that a form on the page had a floating error, ending in it instead of centering itself in the middle of the page like I had originally planned, sticking to the right side of the screen until the page decreases in size and it changes to accommodate to a much smaller screen such as a phone, but even then it is still floating right.

Pictures are attached.

I know it sounds confusing in the way I'm explaining it, but once you see the issue I'm sure there is a relatively easy fix, I have just been unable to find it.

It's confusing to me, because the same logic is basically applied to the text at the top of the page, and they seem to work flawlessly.

The form that has a floating error before the error occurred:
[image: form prior to error]

The form that has floating error after error:
[image: form w/floating error]

Text at the top of the page prior to adjusting to accommodate a smaller screen size
[image: text @ top of page prior to adjusting to accommodate a smaller screen size]

Text at the top of the page after adjusting to accommodate a smaller screen size
[image: text @ top of page after adjusting]

I've tried clearing the float several times, and at this point, I'm quite frankly confused with the number of attempts I've made to resolve this issue.

Here's the HTML & CSS for the form:

HTML:

```
<!--CONTACT US FORM-->
        <div id="contact">
            <h3>Contact Us</h3>
            <form class="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
                    <div class="label-spacer"><label>Name</label></div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
                    <div class="label-spacer"><label>Email</label></div>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                    <div class="label-spacer"><label>Message</label></div>
                        <textarea type="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                    <a class="btn" type="submit">Submit</button></a>
            </form>
        </div>
```

ALL RELEVANT CSS FOR THE FORM:
Without media queries CSS:

```
#content {
    margin-top: 1%;
    float:left;
    width:65%;
}
```

/* Contact Box */

```
#contact{
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    max-width:600px;
    background:#35424a;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    padding:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.contact-form input, .contact-form textarea{
    width:90%;
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

.contact-form input{
    border: 2px solid #ccc; 
}

.contact-form textarea{
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

With media queries CSS:

```
@media(max-width: 768px){
    #content,
    #topleft,
    #topright{
        float:clear;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }


    #contact{
        float:clear;
        width:90%;
        background:#35424a;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
        color:#ffffff;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding:15px;
    }

#contact form input[type="email"], .contact-form input, .contact-form textarea{
        width:90%;
        margin-bottom:7px;
    }

@media(max-width: 1230px){
(SAME AS THE OTHER MEDIA QUERY ABOVE)
}
```

!!!HERE IS ALSO THE HTML AND CSS OF THE TEXT AT THE TOP OF THE PAGE!!!

HTML:

```
<!--HEADER & SHOWCASE BACKGROUND CONTAINER-->
    <div id="h-s-b-container">

        <!--HEADER-->
        <div id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="topleft">
                    <h2>Fleet/Facilities Management & Consultancy</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="topright">
                    <h2>N/A</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#header{
    color:#ffffff;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    min-height:70px;
    border-bottom:#ffffff 2px solid;
}

#topleft{
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

#topright{
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}

    #content,
    #topleft,
    #topright{
        float:clear;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }
```

P.S: Sorry about the amount of code, next time I'll opt to use a service such as Pastebin.

There aren't any error messages as the issue lies within the CSS. As you can see from the pictures above, I expect the form to center itself in the middle of the page, but it keeps floating right.

Comment: instead float: clear change to clear: both. Please minimize your code or move it to a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions, and sorry it took me this long to finally issue an answer to my question.

Unfortunately, no matter what suggestions I tried, it failed to work.

But upon stumbling on an article not too long ago, I figured out how to solve my problem.

The first step was to encase the whole contact form (the div known as contact and everything else inside of it) in an outer div.

Then after encasing the div contact, I took to the css and gave that newly created div, *text-align: center;*

After doing that, I went back to the div contact (#contact) and gave it a display value of *inline-block*.

I hope if you stumble upon this question, it will hopefully help your struggles.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked but looking at first sight it seems possible you haven't assigned a media query for `.contact-form`.

A much easier way would be to wrap it in a container div and then apply `display: flex` and then in the media query add `flex-direction: column` then add `justify-content: center`.

That should be the best way to get the result I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to play with the code, I believe the problem is with the media queries, furthermore, you shouldn't write `float: clear;`

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}

#contact{
    width:90%;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    max-width:100%;
    background:#35424a;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    padding:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 600px;
}

.contact-form input, .contact-form textarea{
    width:90%;
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

.contact-form input{
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.contact-form textarea{
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}


#content {
    margin-top: 1%;
    float:left;
    width:65%;
}



.contact-form input, .contact-form textarea{
    width:90%;
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

.contact-form input{
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.contact-form textarea{
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    #content,
    #topleft,
    #topright{

        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }


   #contact{

        width:40%;
        background:#35424a;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
        color:#ffffff;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding:15px;
    }

#contact form input[type="email"], .contact-form input, .contact-form textarea{
        width:90%;
        margin-bottom:7px;
        }

    @media(max-width: 1230px){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, I don't believe you should be using `float: clear` here.

I haven't fully scanned all the code, but to me, it looks as though you never truly overwrite the `float: right` property that is stated for the div before the media query.
In the media query, state something like `display: block; width: 100%;` (if you want it full width, and then just have the fields be like 30% of the total width and float centre as they already are).